# Why does a higher range product answer results in 0 for kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Why does `(1..100)` reduce for product work ?

```
>>> (1..100).toList().reduce { acc, i -> acc * i }
0
>>> (1..10).toList().reduce { acc, i -> acc * i }
3628800
```

Thanks

Comment: The result of `reduce` method has the same type with the collection's element, which refer to `int` in this case. The 1st one exceeds `int` max value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically the value overflows. It is very clear when you do it using longs too:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Max int: " + Int.MAX_VALUE)
    println("1..12 int: " + (1..12).toList().reduce { acc, i -> acc * i })
    println("1..12 long: " + (1L..12L).toList().reduce { acc, i -> acc * i })
    println("---")
    println("Max long: " + Long.MAX_VALUE)
    println("1..13 int: "  + (1..13).toList().reduce { acc, i -> acc * i })
    println("1..13 long: "  + (1L..13L).toList().reduce { acc, i -> acc * i })
}
```

Output:

```
Max int: 2147483647
1..12 int: 479001600
1..12 long: 479001600
---
Max long: 9223372036854775807
1..13 int: 1932053504
1..13 long: 6227020800
```

Up to 12, the resulting value of the multiplications is always smaller than the `Int.MAX_VALUE` and, as you can see above, the result returned by using ints and longs is the same.

From 13 on, OTOH, the result changes. When using `int`s the values overflow and result begins to be wrong. `long` still works (and, as you can see, the returned value is larger than `Int.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that the value is higher than it's limit.